# Matlab scatter two matrices - issue

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I am trying to figure out how the `scatter` function works in MATLAB.
For example , I have the two matrices:

```
 mat1 = rand(20,20);
 mat2 = rand(20,20);
```

At this point I need to open a figure and use the `scatter` function to display a scatter plot of the values in `mat1` versus the values in `mat2`.
What I did is:

```
figure()
scatter(mat1,mat2)
```

Obvious that is wrong. But I don't know how to do that. In addition I read the documentation about the `scatter` function in the MATLAB docs [Scatter Function - MATLAB DOCS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `scatter` function expects vectors (Matrixes with either one row or one column), try

```
figure()
scatter(mat1(:),mat2(:))
```

The `(:)` operator turns matrixes into vectors.

Comment: By the way, you know how to distinguish the matrices values? for example mat1 vectors will be red and the other blue

Comment: @OfirAttia, The command I wrote will treat `mat1` as `x` values, and `mat2` as `y` values. What did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Scatter is just a way of ploting data. Scatter will plot data as points without connecting them. try

```
mat1= rand(1,20) 
mat2= rand(1,20) 
subplot(121) 
scatter(mat1,mat2); 
subplot(122) 
plot(mat1,mat2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in response to the OP's comment requesting how to set different markers to different colors.

**Approach 1: Logical Indexing**
Requires you to define the index for each color. In the example below, red markers are selected randomly; the remaining markers will be blue.

[image: 2D Scatter plot using different colors via logical indexing]

```
% MATLAB R2017a
mat1 = 100*rand(20,1);
mat2 = 100*rand(20,1);

idxRed = rand(20,1)> 0.5;
idxBlue = ~idxRed;

s(1) = scatter(mat1(idxRed),mat2(idxRed),[],'r','filled');
hold on
s(2) = scatter(mat1(idxBlue),mat2(idxBlue),[],'b','filled');

% Cosmetics
daspect([1 1 1])
box on
for j = 1:2
    s(j).MarkerEdgeColor = 'k';    
    s(j).MarkerFaceAlpha = 0.3;    % Transparency control
end
```

**Approach 2: Custom Colormap**
Create a custom [colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) that directly maps to colors you want.  In the example below, the color map only contains two colors. The logical variable `idxRed` only has two possible values, so the call `caxis([0 1])` is unnecessary here.

[image: 2D Scatterplot with markers colored using colormap]

```
% Create custom colormap  
col1 = [0 1 0]; % Green 
col2 = [1 0 0]; % Red
cmap = [col1;col2];
% Plot
colormap(cmap), hold on, box on
scatter(mat1,mat2,[],idxRed,'filled');
```